# Debugging network connections on the iPad. Any tools or techniques?

Tags: ios5, https, dns, network-tools

I'm trying to get my iPad (3rd gen) to access a website on my workstation over an `https` connection (though I should perhaps mention I cannot connect to it over HTTP either). The aim is to have a working demo of two-way authentication with certificates.

I've installed the client cert on the iPad and a number of Windows and OSX machines on our network. But the iPad seems to be having trouble getting the IP from the local DNS server or perhaps hitting the DNS server at all. As there doesn't seem to be a `Hosts` file or any way of debugging the network side of the iPad I'm a bit stuck.

Does anyone have any hints/tips/tools that could make my life half-way bearable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately things like you mention aren't built in in iOS. I would have a look in the App Store and get an app to perform pings and do DNS lookups. Maybe [NetTools](http://itunes.apple.com/nl/app/nettools/id297964828?mt=8) could work for you?

Comment: NetTools was just what I was looking for, thanks for the suggestion. Its a shame Apple didn't see fit to include this suite of (fairly standard) tools for the convenience of more technical iOS users :-(

Comment: I'm looking for solutions for the same problem. I'm trying to debug webSocket communication flow from the ipad side and did not yet found a workflow for it. I'll try the suggested app!